# I installed a game; where can I find it?

Tags: launcher, games

I just downloaded the Snake game by installing the package `gnome-nibbles`.

I can find it on the terminal but not on the desktop....

Where is it?  How can I add a shortcut to the game on the desktop?

Comment: you can find in dashboard , and after application is opened just lock it to the launcher by right clicking on the icon and selecting the appropriate option(lock to launcher).